# Does BeginSendTo prefix a message with a 4 Byte integer of the size?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, protocols

I inherited a project that includes a dialog between two applications. One in native C++ the other in VB.NET. The protocol is such that the first 4 bytes (32 bits) of the message encodes the size. However the VB.NET side never sets these first four bytes, however it does use the .net method BeginSendTo, which accepts an argument for size.

So my question is; Does the BeginSendTo method automatically add the size to the beginning of the message in the form of a 4 byte int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The `size` argument to the `BeginSendTo()` method indicates how many bytes of the `buffer` argument to actually send.  See [the MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsendto.aspx) for details.